# How to control the number of divs in a column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm attempting to complete a coding challenge that produces a layout of three columns containing four boxes, so that the center column maintains 2 boxes, and the surrounding columns maintain 1 box vertically centered when viewed on a desktop:

[image]

And one column containing all four boxes on mobile:

[image]

Where I'm struggling is figuring out the desktop layout.

I've looked into grid vs. flexbox vs. columns, but it's not clear to me which (if any) are right for this project. Any suggested approaches? (By "approaches" I'm not requesting specific code, just a desirable layout method you'd recommend.)

Here's my HTML as requested below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Four card feature section</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution {
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .attribution a {
      color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="top-text">
      <div>Reliable, efficient delivery</div>
      <div>Powered by Technology</div>
      <div>
        Our Artificial Intelligence powered tools use millions of project data points
        to ensure that your project is successful
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-boxes">
      <div class="info-box">
        Supervisor
        Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks
      </div>
      <div class="info-box">
        Team Builder
        Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project
      </div>
      <div class="info-box">
        Karma
        Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality
      </div>
      <div class="info-box">
        Calculator
        Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
      Coded by <a href="#">Aaron McDonald</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please at least provide some HTML from which the volunteers who answer questions here can answer. You're already asking a lot: make a responsive layout so that "every size between the desktop and mobile layout ... feel[s] responsive."  It would also be nice to see some effort on your part to show what research you've done and how you've tried to apply that research to your problem.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to "solve it" for me. A simple, "Well, I think flexbox would be best to create the three column layout you're after, for 'x' reason..." would suffice. I'm not even asking for code.

Comment: Is the issue that you're not allowed to change the HTML at all?

Comment: @Aaron You could use floats, flex, or grid to accomplish that design. Doesn't matter what is "right" because you said you doing a challenge, and should know the difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this works with every browser, but at least here in the snippet it works:

- `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column`, `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `justify-content: center;` on the container to get the columns and  the vertical centering.
- `width: 30%` (or a little more) and `page-break-inside: avoid;` (to avoid them being split across columns - this property works as well for columns) on the children
- force a "page-break" (actually column-break) after the first and third child (see below)
- Plus a media query resetting those page-breaks and setting the childrens' width to full width for mobile screens.

```css
.info-boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.info-box {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 5px 0;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.info-box:nth-child(1),
.info-box:nth-child(3) {
  page-break-after: always;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .info-box {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .info-box:nth-child(1),
  .info-box:nth-child(3) {
    page-break-after: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="info-boxes">
  <div class="info-box">
    Supervisor Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks
  </div>
  <div class="info-box">
    Team Builder Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project
  </div>
  <div class="info-box">
    Karma Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality
  </div>
  <div class="info-box">
    Calculator Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "I am not sure if this works with every browser, but at least here in the snippet it works" - If it doesn't work in the browser, it doesn't work in the snippet in that browser

Comment: so? .............

Comment: Just pointing that out.

Comment: *...for adding CSS code?* Possibly? OP said they didn't want code but I don't see how an answer to this could be useful without it. Maybe someone took issue with you providing a solution to a coding challenge; there are a couple of comments chiding the OP for asking for help. (FWIW, Frontendmentor.io has solutions on their web site.)